# Prevent UIButton showsTouchWhenHighlighted from altering VoiceOver description

Tags: ios, uikit, accessibility, ios14, voiceover

Setting showsTouchWhenHighlighted, e.g. via the IB option "Shows Touch On Highlight," on a button without a title will alter the VoiceOver description. After reading the accessibility label, VoiceOver beeps and announces a description of the image. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `accessibilityContainerType` value to `UIAccessibilityContainerTypeSemanticGroup` works and that's great  but I'm not sure that
this is the goal of this element.
Even if a button my be seen as a container, I understood this instance property dealt with
[data-based containers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/uiaccessibilitycontainertype) rather.

I looked into your problem that arouse my curiosity and couldn't find out an appropriate solution with the Apple API unfortunately.

First, I thought that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65944947/3825084) may help but it didn't work as you mentioned in your comment... thanks.

Apparently, when the `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` property is used, **there's an added view inside the button that renders the glow touch** ⟹ this is a UIButtonBarPressedIndicator image you can detect thanks to the Debug Hierarchy in Xcode for instance.

This new image seems to put the default value of the accessibility trait property of your button image even if you have already changed it programmatically.

So, in order to avoid VoiceOver from using the screen recognition and reading out some useless information, I made something very ugly but efficient to reach your goal in the `viewDidAppear` for instance *(see the 'basic operations' sheet of this [link](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#element-trait))*:

```
myButton.subviews.forEach{$0.accessibilityTraits = .none}
```

Bad hack due to a native problem of implementation or a simple line of code that anyone can understand, this solution **removes every possible VoiceOver screen recognition from the button** ... and I'm still interested if you can explain a little bit the reason why your solution works, please.

Answer (score 1):

Set `accessibilityContainerType = UIAccessibilityContainerTypeSemanticGroup`.

Comment: This solution works, thanks and  but I can't explain why... if you have an explanation to add to your answer, I'll be very interested in reading it. At first sight, it looks more like a workaround than a real solution, doesn't it? 